# how can i set full height of column inside cover

Tags: wordpress, layout, containers

I am trying to achieve the following in wordpress:

[image]

I tried using a cover with a background image and two columns inside the cover, but for some reason the right column which has a background color with some transparency  is not fitting all the height of the cover image. The result is like a floating square instead of the splitting cover area i want.